# returning data in json with jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

```
var thumb = $('img#thumb');

    new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
        action: 'upload.php',
        name: 'image',
                autoSubmit:'json',
        onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
            $('div.preview').addClass('loading');

        },
        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            thumb.load(function(){
                $('div.preview').removeClass('loading');
                thumb.unbind();
            });
            thumb.attr('src',pic.response);
        }
    });
```

php file:

```
<?php
$arr = array ('pic'=>'img/img.jpg');

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

but its not sending it back i dnt think!!! i tried using firebug, but it dnt show that its posting, to upload.php!!

Comment: im using calums ajax upload plugin by the way https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload

Comment: If Firebug indicates that the POST operation is not occuring, then the PHP is not relevant. You need to do some debugging on the event handlers and form fields.

Comment: yeh i know, im so confused!!! thier might be something wrong with the plugin!!!

Comment: http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload can someone please look at this TUT for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that you're sending any data in your code. Take a look to the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) especially to `data` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are looking for `response.pic` and not `pic.response`.

You are also failing to specify: `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: it is ok not sending header because some dumb browsers don't understand that and save the response as a download. In order to read the json use Jquery's `parseJSON` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @getaway — just use that as the first line of the PHP script.

Comment: @s3ven — which browsers will try to save a JSON response (with the correct content type) as a download if it is requested using XHR? … oh, this is going to be trying to deal with it using an iframe if there is a file upload, isn't it?

Comment: @david thanks david, i actually dnt think its the jason problem, this jquery is not sending the data to post, as shown on firebug!!

Comment: @David I just read that info somewhere, and it referred to some non-popular browsers. I don't know what's the deal with the iframe, I just understood that it's not good to send this header. For example: http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/06/06/problems-with-internet-explorer-and-applicationjson/